# Change application name after app was published

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have an already published on the AppStore app called `AB XYZ`. **I don't want the users to be able to find that app in the AppStore searching for `AB`**, so I've decided to rename the app to be `XYZ` only.

I know, that to change the app name, I need to modify `CFBundleDisplayName` key in the plist.

But will it be sufficient enough so that after I push an update to the AppStore the app name will change on users devices? And will searching for `AB` no longer show my `XYZ` app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you need to update `CFBundleDisplayName` in your plist, this value controls the name that appears under your app icon on a user's phone.

When you make your submission, you will also need to make sure that you remember to change the name of the app in iTunesConnect as this controls how your app is displayed in the App Store. Once you create a new version in iTunesConnect, you can change the name via the `App Information` page, and it will go live with your next approved submission.

While you are submitting, you will also need to make sure you update the app keywords via the `X.x.x Waiting for upload` (or whatever state your new version is in) page as these have a significant impact on how users can search for your app.

If you get all of these, you should be good to go.